# Why is the value of specific rotation different in different cases?

Tags: physical-chemistry, stereochemistry

> An unknown compound with a mass of $4.5~\mathrm{g}$ is dissolved in enough carbon tetrachloride to make a total volume of $250~\mathrm{cm^3}$. The observed  rotation of this solution is $+357.75^\circ$ in a $25~\mathrm{cm}$ cell using the sodium D line. But if $4.5~\mathrm{g}$ is dissolved in $125~\mathrm{cm^3}$ we observed  rotation is $+355.50^\circ$. Calculate specific rotation for this compound. (assuming length of polarimeter tube is $1~\mathrm{dm}$)

My approach is starting with the formula stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_rotation#For_solutions).

$$\text{Specific rotation (in first case)} = 
\frac{+357.75^\circ}{\left(\frac{4.5}{250}\right)(1)}=19875^\circ=75^\circ$$

$$\text{Specific rotation (in second case)} =
\frac{+355.50^\circ}{\left(\frac{4.5}{125}\right)(1)}=9875^\circ=155^\circ$$

Any idea why the two answers are different? Did I miss out something?

Comment: Note that the concentration is doubled in the seconds case. Therefore, the expected rotation should be $2\times357.75^\circ=715.50^\circ$, which is more than a full circle. Substracting one circle $(360^\circ)$ gives the indicated $715.50^\circ-360.00^\circ=355.50^\circ$.

Comment: @Loong but the length changes in the second case too!You did'nt take that into account...Initially it was 2.5 dm but finally 1 dm.

Comment: Oh.My bad....25 cm is cell length!

Comment: Yes, the remarks “in a $25\ \mathrm{cm}$ cell” and “assuming length of polarimeter tube is $1\ \mathrm{dm}$” are confusing. If $2.5\ \mathrm{dm}$ was used in the first case, and $1.0\ \mathrm{dm}$ was used in the second case, then this factor has also to be taken into account.

Comment: The "true" rotation may be the experimentally observed rotation or the experimentally observed rotation +/- (n*180°).  You must find at what multiple of 180° the experimental rotations are equal; this is the "true" rotation.

Comment: @ron You mean a rotation of $+181^{0}$ should be written as $-179^{0}$ ?

Comment: No, an experimentally observed rotation of +181° may actually be +181, +1, +361, -179, etc. That is why the experiment is run at 2 concentrations, then you can solve the equation and determine the "true" rotation.

Comment: Wait a sec!I did'nt get you @ron Which equation should I solve? (You may take the question in the post as an example if you wish )

Comment: You mean something like $\theta_1 + n\pi=\theta_2+m\pi$ ?But there can be infinite solutions of such an equation...

Comment: There is a second condition relating to the change in concentration and path length.  For example, you measure a rotation of 10°, this may really be 10, 190, -170, etc.  Now, repeat the experiment at 1/10 the concentration - is the observed rotation 1, 19, -17, etc.

Comment: @ron I'm still not sure if I understood you.Suppose in the first case we get a specific rotation $75^{0}$ and in second case we get a  specific rotation $155^{0}$ what will be the true rotation according to you?

Comment: If indeed the path lengths are equal, then rot_1=357.75 + (n*180) and, due to concentration 2*rot_1 = rot_2.  Solving we find that n=-2, therefore rot_1 = 357.75 +(-2*180) or -2.25.  This "true" observed value may now be converted to the specific rotation using your formula.

Comment: @Loong I took the liberty to correct that O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If indeed the path lengths are equal, then $rot_1=357.75 + (n*180)$ and, due to concentration $2*rot_1 = rot_2$. Solving we find that $n=-2$, therefore $rot_1 = 357.75 +(-2*180)$ or $-2.25$. This "true" observed value may now be converted to the specific rotation using your formula.

-by @ron in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

A polarimeter is typically a long cylindrical tube with flat ends. I think the 25 cm was referring to the diameter of the tube. The other wrinkle here is that the angle measurement may be + or -. So 357.75 may in fact be -2.25.

Specific Rotation (in first case)=$$\frac{-2.25^{0}}{(\frac{4.5}{250})(1)}= - 125^{0}$$

Specific Rotation (in second case)=$$\frac{-4.50^{0}}{(\frac{4.5}{125})(1)}=-125^{0}$$

Comment: Could you check my calculation in the original question please?Why is the answer not matching if I take the original values with +ve sign?

Comment: @ZOZ - How can I do the calculations wrong and get a good answer?

Comment: I never said your answer is wrong or your calculation is wrong.I'm asking why is my calculation wrong?Where did I go wrong?See the question...

Comment: Your problem was that you assumed that the reading for the solutions were positive when the are in fact negative. Think of a 360 degree compass. If you draw an angle of +357.75 degrees that is the same as drawing an angle of -2.25 degrees.

Comment: In other words think of a 360 degree compass from geometry class. They are graduated from 0 to 360. There are no negative markings. A polarimeter is setup the same way. There are no negative angles on the actual dial.

Comment: So you mean if the observed angle is >$180^{0}$ then we must take angle as negative in the calculation? I've never read something like that..could you cite a source?

Comment: Molecules can rotate light + or -. If a solution rotates light -10 degrees, then half the concentration will rotate the light -5 degrees. But my readings will be 350 degrees for the first solution and 355 degrees for the second solution since a  polarimeter doesn't have - degrees.